# How i can show same data from listView to second activity in android like, if i clicked on google , it show google on second activity

Tags: java, android, oracle, listview, android-intent

This code fetching data from database using wamp server in listView, but I have to do if I click on row # 1 it shows row # 1 on second activity , if I click on 2 it shows row # 2 on second activity,

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class attendence extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendence);

        String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
        getJSON("http://192.168.0.102/A/select.php" + "?username=" + name);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV);

        // TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_success_name);
        //
        // Intent intent = getIntent();
        // String loginName = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        // txtname.setText("Welcome, " +loginName);
    }

    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {

                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();

    }

    //
    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("Result");
        String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            heroes[i] = obj.getString("ID") + " " + obj.getString("STATUS") + "  " + obj.getString("ATD_DATE");
            if (!obj.getString("STATUS").toString().equals("A")) {
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(attendence.this, atd_leave_form.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            } else {

            }

            // Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"GREEN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

I just want to show same single data on which I clicked in list view in android.
thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

By using intents you have to implement that in onItemClick method

Check this [Passing Data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

also you can find useful info in the [android site](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)